# Twitter like search for users using Elasticsearch and python

Tags: search, elasticsearch, n-gram

I am trying to build a twitter like search for users using elasticsearch and python. That is a search across `first_name, last_name and username.`  I have decided to go in with ngram. This is how the analyzer is configured:

```
 settings = {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "mynGram"
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "mynGram": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an index size of 700 MB for about 700,000 documents. This covers most of my use cases but one:

1. `John`    - Gives a set of results
2. `John D`  - Gives the same set of results as 'John'
3. `John Do` - Gives the correct set of results.

My guess is that because of the min. ngram size being 2, it creates a blind spot in query 2 above. I have the option of reducing min. ngram size to 1 but I am worried about scalability and performance issues.

Is ngram the correct approach considering scalability and performance?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your mapping definition. With an ngram analyzer, you want the `index_analyzer` to be `ngram_analyzer`, but **not** the `search_analyzer`.

Otherwise, your query string itself will be split into ngrams. `John` becomes `Jo`, `oh`, `hn`, etc. and a `term` or `match` filter will match any of those tokens.

Documentation: [Index time search-as-you-type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html#_querying_the_field)

On a related note, if you intend to do only prefix searches, an [`edge-ngram` tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4//analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) would be more appropriate and would use less memory (both RAM and disk).

Comment: Nope, I am using a standard analyzer during search.

Comment: Hmmm, can you post your mapping definition?